Proving a module is injective (or not) and failed attempt using Baer's Criterion.
Consider the left $R$- module $M$ where  $M=\{\left(\begin{array}{c} \mathbb{Z}_{2}\\  \mathbb{Z}_{2}\end{array}\right)\}$ and $R= \begin{pmatrix}
\mathbb{Z}_{2} & \mathbb{Z}_{2}  \\
0 & \mathbb{Z}_{2}
\end{pmatrix}$ and the action is given by the canonical matrix multiplication. I would like to see if this module is (or not) and injective left $R$- module. I was thinking of using Baer's criterion, since I already know all the left ideals of this ring, namely:

$\begin{bmatrix}0&\mathbb{Z}_{2}\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$
$\begin{bmatrix}\mathbb{Z}_{2}&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$
$\begin{bmatrix}\alpha&\alpha\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ for $\alpha\in \mathbb{Z}_{2}$
$\begin{bmatrix}0&\mathbb{Z}_{2}\\0&\mathbb{Z}_{2}\end{bmatrix}$
$\begin{bmatrix}\mathbb{Z}_{2}&\mathbb{Z}_{2}\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$

Plus the trivial ideals, of course. The Baer´s criterion I've tried is the one found in Bland's Rings and their Modules in Proposition 5.1.3 which states that the following statement is equivalent to the fact of $M$ being a left injective module:
For each left ideal $A$ of $R$ and each $R$ linear mapping $f:A  \to M$ there is an $x \in M$ such that $f(a) =ax$ for all $a \in A$.
Ideally I was looking for a left ideal $A$ of $R$ and an element  $0 \neq x \in M$ such that $f(a) \neq ax$ for some $a \in A$. The thing is computing all the morphisms $f:A  \to M$ which hold or not hold the condition previously stated is nuts!!! So far from what I've had computed it seems like the module $M$ it's gonna be injective. Perhaps there is an easier way to prove it or maybe I'm overlooking a combination of a particular $f: A \to M$, $x \in M$ and $a \in A$ where $f(a)  \neq ax$. Thanks for reading. This question is self-contained but it is indirectly related to my previous three questions.

Not helpful for this question, but if there was a $F_2$ linear map $R\to F_2$, which was non-trivial on all the (non-trivial) left ideals, then all projectives such as $M$ would be injective.  Unfortunately in this case, the best you can do is four out of the five on your list, so this method does not work.

Again I prefer to use $F_2$ for clarity and ease of typing.
One thing that simplifies the situation here is how many summands of $R$ there are.  Each one that is a direct summand of $_RR$ easily satisfies Baer's hypotheses, because given $f:Re\to M$, you can take the zero map on $R(1-e)\to M$ and then the direct sum map is defined $R\to M$, and that extends $f$.
Now, this ring is not semisimple, it must certainly have a left ideal that is not a summand: it turns out there are two: $L_1=\begin{bmatrix}F_2&F_2 \\ 0&0\end{bmatrix}$ which is itself isomorphic to the direct sum of two other simple left ideals, and $L_2=\begin{bmatrix}0&F_2 \\ 0&0\end{bmatrix}$.
It's also helpful that $M\cong \begin{bmatrix}0&F_2 \\ 0&F_2\end{bmatrix}$, so we'll just use that copy as $M$.  Considering that the annihilator for every element of $L_1$ necessarily contains $M$, and the fact that $ann(x)\subseteq ann(f(x))$ for any homomorphism $f$, we see that any potential $f$ must map $L_1$ into $\begin{bmatrix}0&F_2\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$.  The same is true for any homomorphism $L_2\to M$.
For $L_1$ this allows for four possible maps, one of which is zero.
It's not hard to see the remaining maps are effected by $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$.
For $L_2$ the only possible maps are the identity map and the zero map, both of which are trivially extensible to $R$.
With that verified, Baer's criterion holds, and $M$ is injective.

@tkf Ugh thanks, sorry I forgot to comment on that one.  I will add a placeholder now and correct it soon.

@tkf Just swung around today to fix things. Thanks again for the careful reading and the heads-up.

First and foremost, thank you so much. However, it is not clear why every map $f$ from $L_{1}$  is mapped into $L_{2}$. I mean I get the remarks, $ann(x) \subseteq ann(f(x))$ and $M$ in every element from annhilator of $L_{1}$ but how this leads to  $L_{1}$ mapped into $M_{2}$? Also wondering what does it mean that a maps are effected by the three matrices you propose? Does it mean I take every element from $L_{1}$ and send them to this matrices? Again, thank you so much.

@Cos The annihilator of $x$ limits where you can map $x$.  Since $L_2$ annihilates both $L_2$ and $L_1$ on the left, you can only send it to submodules of $M$ annihilated by $L_2$ on the left.  The only such submodule is $L_2$.  And yes, if you simply write down the three nonzero maps, you can see by inspection they are extended by those matrices.

O.K thanks, the first part is a little bit clearer but still I'm struggling with the 3 non trivial morphism $f: L_{1} \to L_{2}$. I mean I don't know if each of these ones are determined by these matrices you mentioned. $L_{1}$  has four elements and $L_{2}$ just two and some of the matrices you mentioned are not even in $L_{1}$ or $L_{2}$. So I'm wondering if we can compute just one of these morphism that can be extended? I would try to figure out the other two non trivial morphisms from $L_{1}$ to $L_{2}$. I answered late because I've been trying to compute these morphisms. Thanks

$L_1$ has only four elements to map.  You know where 0 goes. If you pick two more, the third one must comply.

$\require{AMScd}$
This problem can be easily solved by using the language of quiver representations for finite-dimensional algebras over a field. If you are not familiar with this theory, it is a very fruitful tool in representation theory of finite-dimensional algebras; I have written a detailed answer in order to be as accesible as possible, though I suggest you to skim through these notes on quiver representations first before reading the answer.
It is easy to see that the ring $R$ is isomorphic to the path $\mathbb{Z}_2$-algebra of the following quiver:
\begin{CD}
1 @>{\alpha}>> 2
\end{CD}
Considering $\epsilon_i$ the trivial path corresponding to the $i$-th vertex, the product in the quiver algebra is given as follows:
$$ \epsilon_1 \cdot \epsilon_1 = \epsilon_1, \quad \alpha \cdot \epsilon_1 = \alpha, \quad \epsilon_2 \cdot \alpha = \alpha, \quad \epsilon_2 \cdot \epsilon_2 = \epsilon_2 $$
The remaining products are $0$. Then, the isomorphism is clearly given by:
$$ \epsilon_1 \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, \quad \alpha \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \quad \epsilon_2 \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$
The framework of quiver algebras is so powerful since we can reduce the problem to linear algebra via the equivalence of categories $\text{Mod}(R) \simeq \text{Rep}(Q)$, the former being the category of left $R$-modules and the latter being the category of $\mathbb{Z_2}$-representations over the quiver $Q$. I will be using the construction of this equivalence later, you can read how to translate modules into representations in the proof of the equivalence given in the previously mentioned notes.
Using elementary linear algebra, one can prove that the following are the only indescomposable representations:
\begin{CD}
 \mathbb{Z}_2 @>>> 0, \quad 0 @>>>\mathbb{Z}_2, \quad \mathbb{Z_2} @>>> \mathbb{Z_2}
\end{CD}
It is easy to check that, using the equivalence $\text{Mod}(R) \simeq \text{Rep}(Q)$, the projective indescomposable representations are precisely:
\begin{CD}
 \mathbb{Z}_2 @>>> \mathbb{Z}_2, \quad 0 @>>> \mathbb{Z}_2
\end{CD}
Moreover, it is easy to see that the representation associated with the module $M$ is the following:
\begin{CD}
 \mathbb{Z}_2 @>>> \mathbb{Z}_2
\end{CD}
In order to prove that $M$ is injective, one can show that $\text{Ext}^1(-,M)$ vanishes. Using Baer's criterion, one just has to show that $\text{Ext}^1(X,M) = 0$ for any finitely-generated $R$-module $X$. Furthermore, since the Krull-Schimdt theorem holds in the case of a path algebra over a quiver, it suffices to prove that $\text{Ext}^1(-,M)$ over indescompsable objects (and, using $\text{Mod}(R) \simeq \text{Rep}(Q)$, one just have to show that it vanishes in the non-projective representations). We are then going to show that $\text{Ext}^1(\mathbb{Z}_2 \to 0,\mathbb{Z}_2 \to \mathbb{Z}_2) = 0$. In order to do this, take the following projective resolution
\begin{CD}
0 @>>> (0 \to \mathbb{Z}_2) @>>> (\mathbb{Z}_2 \to \mathbb{Z}_2) @>>> (\mathbb{Z}_2 \to 0) @>>> 0
\end{CD}
Deleting and applying $\text{Hom}(-,\mathbb{Z}_2 \to \mathbb{Z}_2)$, the following chain complex is obtained:
\begin{CD}
0 @>>> \text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z} _2\to \mathbb{Z}_2,\mathbb{Z}_2 \to \mathbb{Z}_2) @>>> \text{Hom}(0 \to \mathbb{Z}_2,\mathbb{Z}_2 \to \mathbb{Z}_2) @>>> 0
\end{CD}
Computing the hom-sets is trivial, which both are $1$-dimensional $\mathbb{Z}_2$-vector spaces. It is straightforward to conclude that $\text{Ext}^1(\mathbb{Z}_2 \to 0,\mathbb{Z}_2 \to \mathbb{Z}_2) = 0$. All in all, $M$ is indeed an injective $R-$module.
Remark All the previously exposed works for an arbitrary field $k$.

I have just noticed that I am using the caracterization of injectivity via the $\text{Ext}^1$ functor. I am not sure if you are familiar with derived functors; if not, I have an alternative argument if you are interested.

@Javier_Herrero Gracias Javier! Tbh, I'm not very acquainted with quiver algebras but I would love to delve into the topic, therefore I appreciate the notes that you linked. Yes, I'm keen on reading your argument without derived functors. These functors are not completely alien to me but they are not my regular weapon of choice.

After a second thought, even though the computation did not require any derived functors, implicitly the $\text{Ext}^1$ is needed in order to prove the tool I was thinking of. Essentially, I was going to argue that the duality $\text{Hom}(-,k)$ sends projective right $kQ$-modules to injective left $kQ$-modules, where $kQ$ is the quiver algebra (you can look it up in the cited notes).  It is trivial to compute the projective indescomposable right $kQ$-modules, so you just needed to check that, indeed, one of these indescompsables was (isomorphic to) your initial module.
